# Help with my projects Schematic

Tags: led

I am attaching a schematic for a project I am doing , the problem is that it does not work and I don't know why , would anyone on this forum know what is the problem with it .
 excuse me if I have not written this with respect to others that may help me , I am hoping the schematic explains and gives the info to help me ! .[image]

thanks

spike

Comment: What is it doing wrong?  "It doesn't work" is too vague.  Do you mean it doesn't charge the batteries, or do you mean it doesn't light up at all?

Comment: Your other question has been reopened, so you would have been better off updating it.  I've voted to close as duplicate.  Please update your first question with the new schematic and a description of what it does that is wrong.

Comment: You don't describe what it is supposed to do and you don't describe what it's doing. This post is ridiculously broad and impossible to answer without a crystal ball (mine tends to keep breaking down and is currently in the crystal ball repair shop).

Comment: Hi , it is the led not lighting up

Comment: Well it seems that , WhatRoughBeat has a crystal ball that is working , or could it be that he or she has a little more sense and patience and more helpfull ! .

Comment: @Spike1947 he still had to *guess*. If you asked your question PROPERLY and according to the RULES, nobody would have to guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is that the LEDs don't turn on.

In that case, I would suspect that your choice of MOSFETs is wrong - you need one with a logic-level gate voltage. Assume for the moment that the battery is fully charged, and putting out 2.6 volts. Then the sun goes down and the solar cell output drops to zero. Now, since the 1 M resistor comes into play, the gate voltage is zero as well, and the gate-source voltage is 2.6 volts.

The difficulty with this setup is that 2.6 volts will not guarantee operation for most MOSFETs. The typical Vgs(th) is in the range of 2 to 4 volts, and this is usually specified for a current of about 250 uA. With a nominal 2.2 volts required for the LEDs, the MOSFET will need to be turned on hard to allow operation, and this will require considerably greater Vgs - like, at least 5 volts for guaranteed operation. And it should be pretty obvious that you're not going to get this from a 2.6 volt battery.

It is possible to find logic-level MOSFETs which have a (typical) Vgs(th) of 1 to 2 volts, and there are some even more sensitive than that. I suggest you start looking for something along those lines.

Comment: Hi , thanks for that , yes it is that the Led's do not light , so will try as you suggest to look for s different mindset , you seem to be the only one on here is helpfully , thanks . Spike